# XtraGrid set selection on match datamember

Tags: devexpress

We want to set the selection on a XtraGrid based on a List collection from the same type as the datamember of an XtraGrid.

The way we do it now is to iterate the gridview rows.

```
private void SetSelectedRowsInternal(IList<StrongType> collecshung)
    {
        grdvSomeGrid.ClearSelection();
        grdvSomeGrid.BeginSelection();
        for (int i = 0;i < grdvSomeGrid.RowCount;i++)
        {
            StrongType _strongTyped = ((StrongType)grdvSomeGrid.GetRow(i));
            if (collecshung.Where(x => x.Id == _strongTyped.Id).Count() == 1)
                grdvSomeGrid.SelectRow(i);
        }
        grdvSomeGrid.EndSelection();
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you fill your grid ... You can directly iterate on the `BindingList` for instance (using `LINQ`). But if you find that it is taking more time than needed, then it should be because `LINQ` functions can be hit more than 1 million time even for a small amount of data.

I recommend you to use a dictionary instead of a `LINQ`ed collection.